# Debugging lmer function

Tags: r, lme4

I am trying to feed a hierarchical model with the `lmer` function from the `lme4 package` but lattely while trying new dataset for my code I encountered an error that occurs when the `chol` function is called from the monadicbase function:

```
"Debug location is approximate because source code is not available"
chol.default <- function(x, pivot = FALSE, LINPACK = FALSE, tol = -1, ...)
{
    if (is.complex(x))
        stop("complex matrices not permitted at present")

    .Internal(La_chol(as.matrix(x), pivot, tol))
}
```

By searching within the lmer code on Github, I figured out that the `chol` function is called from the `checkConv` function within the package `lme4`.

My problem is that I do not understand why I get this message all the time with a specific dataset. Clearly, when I get the result at the end, it is incorrect and I don't know how to step inside the `lmer` code to start debugging that issue since I do not find the same arborescence at all inside my downloaded package and can't find where the used code is.

I sadly do not have a reproducible example for you but if you could give me some tips as to how to start to step in the R code of the `lme4` package in debug mode that would be great !

**UPDATE: showing the info I have on the error**

[image: error message]

The traceback is the following:

```
eval(expr, envir, enclos)
eval(substitute(browser(skipCalls = pos), list(pos = (length(sys.frames()) -
chol.default(Hessian)
chol(Hessian)
```

Comment: Please show the actual error message.

Comment: It is not really an error message. The code stops and Rstudio starts to display the above message that is created by the function `chol` called inside `checkConv` inside the `lmer` function

Comment: The cholesky decomposition function `chol` checks if your input matrix is compex through `is.complex(x)` which happens to be true in your case and in `?chol` , it is currently available for real matrices only.

Comment: My input matrix is not complex. The dependant variables are only composed of dummy variables and the independant and level ones are positive numeric values. It is the `Hessian` computed by the lmer function that becomes complex which in my opinion makes no sense... I would like to be able to step into the lmer code but when I open the `lmer.R` file there is no relevant code.

Comment: Your RStudio is stepping into debug mode. There should be another tab where is shows R output and the error message. If there isn't, change your RStudio setting so that you get the actual error message or run the code in Rgui. You also need to show how you call `lmer`.

Comment: Big news, now the above issue is solved. I updated lme4 and my R version and at least that part of the problem is solved. However, the model fail to converge using either bobyqa or Nelder_Mead optimizer. This is strange as the model is very simple. Here it probably crashes because each subgroup should have exactly the same coef. But as I understand it that should not create any problem. Maybe it should be a different question now for cross-validated ?